# How to track the USB storage devices connected to my Windows Server 2008R2 machine

Tags: windows, file-transfer, usb-storage, windows-server-2008-r2, authorization

We would like to monitor the unauthorized file copy from our local server to USB storage devices. We are not sure where windows logs all the USB storage devices connections.

Please tell me, Is there any way to see the history/log of all USB devices connected to our server?

Comment: I think you want logging independent of windows logs/registry (tenable software), anyone with intent will erase/modify the registry entry for their device. When all else fails use video surveillance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exact times, generally no.

[USB dev view](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) should give you an idea what devices were used, and when they were first seen by the system. This is based off a registry entry and other information.

If you're interested in doing this manually [forensics wiki](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/USB_History_Viewing) explains that this information is stored in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USBSTOR\` as well as setupapi.log. If you periodically clear those those places, it may give you an idea if the device was reattached or reinstalled

Answer (score 2):

This may be done with an audit software like *Nessus*:

*Track and monitor USB device usage* (Video 3:16 min)
http://www.tenable.com/expert-resources/videos/1078

Nessus 5 support Windows XP, Server 2003, Server 2008, *Server 2008 R2*, Vista, and 7 (i386 and x86-64)

Hope this help. Let us know.

Answer (score 2):

I went digging for a better way to find this information because I didn't like the idea of third party software when I'm sure Windows Event Viewer could handle this. Here's how you can track your USB connects and disconnects (and other hardware updates) through the Windows Event Viewer.

- Launch Windows Event Viewer, you can do this by going to Windows Search or Run Box (Win+R) and type:

  ***eventvwr***
- Press ***Enter*** (to launch the Windows Event Viewer)
- At the top of the Event Viewer window, click on "***Action***" → "***Create Custom View...***"
- Choose all of "***Event Levels***" (***Critical, Warning, Verbose, Error, Information***)
- Select "***By Source***"
- For "***Event sources:***" scroll down on the list and choose "***Kernel-PnP***"

You may need to scroll to later pages to see more recent data. You will also be shown a hardware ID which you can either reference to Device Manager (Check USB device ***Properties*** → ***Details*** → ***Hardware ID***), or simply search the Hardware ID on your favorite search engine.

Kernel-PnP events will show all devices that get added to the machine, not just USB devices, but it works just as well to monitor all hardware changes. If you're not swapping internal components often (most people aren't), the vast majority of what is tracked will be changes to USB devices.

Edit: Certain devices will also show the number of disconnects from the PC.

[image: Example USB Log from Windows Event Viewer: Monitoring Kernel-PnP]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).